# Is the following true for $f: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $f: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow  \Bbb R$  continuous I am asked to prove that if there is an $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ but $f(o,o,o)$ is not zero. Then there exists another $y$ closer to the origin, such that $f(y)=0$

Is this true? I just can´t seem to understand the intuition behind it for, say, $\Bbb R^2$ or  $\Bbb R$.

If it is, how would you prove it?

Comment: If $f(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2$, then $f(1,0,0)=0$ but $f(x,y,z)\ne0$ if $(x,y,z)\ne(1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is true. Consider
$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-1)^2+(x_2-1)^2+(x_3-1)^2
$$
then $f(0)\neq 0$ and $f=0$ precisely at $x=(1,1,1)$ and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

What about this function?
$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$$

Let $x=(1,0,0)$.  Then $f(x)=0$, but for all $y$ such that $f(y)=0$, $|y|=|x|=1$.  So this seems to be a counterexample.